# Convert perl to python3

Tags: python-3.x, perl, comparison

I am trying to re-create a perl code into python3 code. I do not have enough python expertise to do it. Thanks in advance.

I tried (in python) to split() and other thing but I am getting no where.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"file.name.txt") or die;
while(<FILE>){
    chomp;
    my $name = $_;
    $name =~ s/\.Q20L20\.fq\.gz//;
    open(OUT,">$name.sh") or die;
    print OUT "#!/bin/bash\n";
    print OUT "tophat2 -output -input $name.Q20L20.fq.gz";
    print $name;
    close OUT;
 }
 close FILE;
```

the perl script works great but i can't make it into Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in Python 3:

```
import os
import re

with open( "file.name.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        name = line.rstrip()
        name = re.sub(r'\.Q20L20\.fq\.gz', '', name)
        with open(name + '.sh', 'w') as fpw:
            fpw.write("#!/bin/bash" + os.linesep)
            fpw.write("tophat2 -output -input {}.Q20L20.fq.gz".format(name));
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a Perl to Python code language converter specifically for that, you can check it out here :)
https://codelanguageconverter.com/convert-python-to-perl

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32317006)

Comment: With this tool, you hit a paywall if you want to convert anything but canned samples.